# Mapping JSON String to List of POJO gives null values

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapper

I'm getting json from rest api and I want to store the data in list of POJO. Below is the codefor the same:

```
public List<myObject> mapper(){

    String myObjectData= restClient.getAllOriginal("myObject");

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

    CollectionType typeReference =
            TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, myObject.class);
    List<CommitmentPojo> resultDto = null;

    try
    {

         resultDto = objectMapper.readValue(myObjectData, typeReference);
        
    }
    catch (JsonParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultDto;
}
```

I've added `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` configuration as I've extra columns in json as compared to POJO and I can't change POJO(unless and until required) as I'll have to change many more things. I've added `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` configuration for object mapper as I was facing exception in below line: (I suspect this is causing the issue now)

```
// [JACKSON-526]: implicit arrays from single values?
        if (!ctxt.isEnabled(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)) {
            throw ctxt.mappingException(_collectionType.getRawClass());
        }
```

This is from CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray method.

Method which gets the string from rest api:

```
public  String getAllOriginal(String resourcePath) {
       // Objects.requireNonNull(this.baseUri, "target cannot be null");
        return this.client
                .target("http://comtsrvc.ny.qa.flx.nimbus.gs.com:3802/v2/")
                .path(resourcePath)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .cookie("GSSSO", getCookie())
                .get()
                .readEntity(String.class);
    }
```

Below is my json:

```
{
  
  "myObject" : [ {
    "key" : {
      "srcSys" : "REPO_1",
      "srcSysRef" : "20200909_1911_1"
    },
    "productData" : {
      "id" : null,
      "number" : null,
      "isn" : null,
      "productId" : null,
      "productAdditionalData" : {
        "assetClassTree" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
        "description" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
        "productTypeData" : {
          "productType" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
          "productGroup" : "UNCLASSIFIED"
        }
      }
    },
    "state" : "OPEN",
    "type" : "01"
  }, {
    "key" : {
      "srcSys" : "REPO_2",
      "srcSysRef" : "20200403_3892_1"
    },
    "productData" : {
      "id" : "1",
      "number" : "11",
      "isn" : "null",
      "productId" : 1234,
      "productAdditionalData" : {
        "assetClassTree" : "xyz",
        "description" : "abc",
        "productTypeData" : {
          "productType" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
          "productGroup" : "UNCLASSIFIED"
        }
      }
    },
    "state" : "OPEN",
    "tradAcctType" : "01"
  } ]
  }
```

The issue is: all the values are null with the size of list as 1. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Your list of objects is wrapped by extra object. You can deserialise it to a `Map` of `List`-s: `new TypeReference<Map<String, List<myObject>>>(){}` or you can create a new Pojo with `List<MyObject> myObject` property.

Comment: 'm bound to have a list of Pojo. is there any other way, like without creating a new Pojo? If not, can you tell me please tell me how can I use `List<MyObject> myObject` property, if I add it in Pojo.

Comment: I tried to get rid of TypeReference and I tried to use, JavaType as below:
`JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, CommitmentPojo.class);
resultDto = objectMapper.readValue(commitmentsData, javaType);`

But still, the list appears with null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deserialize it to a `Map`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

...

Map<String, List<MyObject>> root = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<MyObject>>>() {});
List<MyObject> objects = root.get("myObject");
```

So you do not need to create a new `POJO` for a root level. `Map` will also work.

Comment: This was really helpful! But I'm stuck at a point, I've date to read which is in the array format, eg [2020, 9, 22] and I'm running into exception:
`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@8a98f38; line: 31, column: 31] (through reference chain: myObjectPojo["startDate"])`

Comment: @shweta, please create a new question with all details: example `JSON`, `POJO` class, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004700/read-array-integer-from-json-and-map-with-pojo
can you please suggest for this